# PDO, can't find whats wrong in my prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make simple search function but there's an error I cannot find why.

I checked the result SQL query is properly generated. However, execute this prepared statement cause unknown failure. Why this `execute()` returns false?

```
public function searchConcept(string $cplx = '', string $name = '', string $desc = '', int $page = 0)
{
    $SQL = 'select * from concept ';
    $SQL_criteria = array();

    // Criteria
    if($cplx) { $SQL_criteria[] = 'cplx:cplx'; }
    if($name) { $SQL_criteria[] = 'name like :name'; }
    if($desc) { $SQL_criteria[] = 'description like :desc'; }
    if($SQL_criteria) { $SQL .= 'where '.implode(' and ', $SQL_criteria).' '; }

    $SQL .= 'limit :page, 15';

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($SQL);

    if($cplx) { $stmt->bindValue(':cplx', $cplx); }
    if($name) { $stmt->bindValue(':name', '%'.$name.'%'); }
    if($desc) { $stmt->bindValue(':desc', '%'.$desc.'%'); }

    $stmt->bindValue(':page', $page*15);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $rst = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $rst;
    } else {
        throw new DBRFError();
    }
}
```

DBRFError is custom error class that I made.

#

Add 1. ####
I think `cplx:cplx` doesn't matter. `$cplx` takes its value something like ">5".
I didn't actually tested that certain situation but I just tested without cplx block and also cause an error.

#

Add 2. ####
I just find the origin of the problem.
`$SQL .= 'limit :page, 15';` it cause the error. I do this for pagenation. Without this block, code works well. However, I can't understand why.

Comment: What if you print your resulting sql and execute it manually?

Comment: I did. and I thinki I found an origin of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have missing '=' in your where clause. This is the fixed code:

```
 if($cplx) { $SQL_criteria[] = 'cplx=:cplx'; }
```